# Is it possible to have multiple VMs running on same machine with individual monitors, mouse and keyboard?

Tags: virtual-machine

I am buying parts to build a fairly powerful machine for myself (i7-6700k, GTX 970, 32 GB RAM, etc for those who'd like to know technical details)

Kids also need their old computers replaced so the thought came to mind what if I could run 4 VMs on my machine giving us 4 workstations with 4 separate monitors, mouse and keyboard to login to their own user accounts and do whatever they like.

Is this something possible? If yes, will it be like 4 VMs running in 4 different tabs on 4 monitors? How cumbersome is it going to be to maintain/operate? Thanks!

Comment: You might want to retag your post. It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the VMS family of operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible however kind of cumbersome mode of operation.

You'll be having a main vmware server for example or even vmware workstation would suffice then you'd simply install all the operating systems you need with the configurations you like.

When you're all set with them. Fire them up and pass each one to a different monitor you like and pair your each mouse and keyboard with individual vm. This configuration can be done easily with vmware menu.

As you can imagine, this is simply a master/slave matter so that your mainframe(actual pc) would have to be running all the time.

If you already have a separate monitor and set of mouse-keyboard, you can give it a shot and see it in action for yourself.

Hope this would help.